# Searching in array using if and match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an issue. I have 3 colums with different quantity of lines. They’re named as “Fruits”; “Vegetables” and “Smth else”. I need to vlookup them to another one column where all this kind of stuff is mixed. E.g. Potato – Veg, Pinapple = Fruit and so on.

I can’t use If function (as If(Cell =B1; “Fruits”;”Veg”)) because it doesn’t search in array (even with using Ctrl + Shift + Enter). Also if(Match…) is working but only for two columns and typing “Not found” if the conduction is wrong.

Screenshot:
http://screenshot.ru/upload/images/2017/06/02/Arraya4229.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$2:$C$11)/($A$2:$C$11=E2),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The formula is just greate! If you can please explain what   "($A$2:$C$11=E2)"   means?